# Ошибка Fatal error: Call to undefined function mbstrlen(). как решить?

Tags: php.ini

1. в php.ini подключена extension=php_mbstring.dll ; перед ним убрана.
2. Вот в phpinfo();

mbstring

```
Multibyte Support                   enabled 
Multibyte string engine             libmbfl 
HTTP input encoding translation     enabled 
libmbfl version                     1.3.2
```

mbstring extension makes use of "streamable kanji code filter and converter", which is distributed under the GNU Lesser General Public License version 2.1.

```
Multibyte (japanese) regex support  enabled
Multibyte regex (oniguruma) version     5.9.2

Directive                            Local Value    Master Value
mbstring.detect_order                  auto auto
mbstring.encoding_translation          On   On
mbstring.func_overload                 0    0
mbstring.http_input                        UTF-8    UTF-8
mbstring.http_output                   UTF-8    UTF-8

mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml)

mbstring.internal_encoding                 UTF-8    UTF-8
mbstring.language                          neutral  neutral
mbstring.strict_detection                      Off  Off
mbstring.substitute_character         no value  no value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что нечаянно добавил лишнюю точку. Убрал. И свою задачу решил.
P.s. Прошу модератора удалить тему.